# Webpack not acting on sideEffects for css files

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

I have a javascript module that imports a CSS file.  The CSS is included in the build in webpack 'development' mode, but not in 'production' mode.  This will be because treeshaking sees the CSS file as not having any side effects.  The recommended way of dealing with this is to add   `"sideEffects": ["*.css"]`to `package.json`, which I have done.  For good measure, I have also added a `sideEffects` property to the css rule in the webpack config. However, the CSS file is still not included.  What more should I do?

Extract from `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "psm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "PRISM: Participatory System Mapping",
  "main": "prism.html",
  "sideEffects": ["*.css"],
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
```

Extract from `webpack.prod.js`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css/,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            sideEffects: true
            },
        ],
    },
```

The import statement is:

```
import "vis-network/dist/vis-network.min.css";
```

This is using npm version 6.1.4 and webpack 4.42.1

Comment: I have a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311982/how-to-successfully-bundle-css-for-dynamic-multi-page-app-using-webpack-5. For me, it is not working in development either though.

Comment: Maybe the issue was `*.css` instead of `**/*.css` ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding  new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),  in plugins
as shown below

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),                     
        new WebpackManifestPlugin()
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have two possible solutions to the above problem

1. (**Recommended**) The version of webpack or webpack cli you are using requires an update. My code started working after I updated the version as below

```
"webpack": "^4.29.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
```

which I upgraded to

```
"webpack": "^4.47.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
```

2. Add the css file directly in config, through the entry setting. For example

```
entry: {
    'test1': [
        './src/my.js',
        './src/my.css',
            ],
```

Hopefully, this helps!